# Toggle icon back "i" element to original position when clicking on another toggle div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do an accordion with the clickable toggle that opens the content, and toggle the icon, i was able to change the content slider on click and once any other content is clicked to get back to the original one, and to toggle the icon on click but not when i click on another toggle to open.
what I'm trying to do is to toggle back the icon to its original position, can you help me out with the function,

thanks

HTML

```
<div id="accordion">   

    <p class="accordion-toggle">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
        <strong>title</strong>
    </p>

    <div class="accordion-content">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
      $(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

          //Expand or collapse this panel
          $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');

          //Hide the other panels
          $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');

        //Toggle icon
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-right fa-angle-down');

        });

      });
```

Comment: Is your full code including HTML and CSS? Put full code here and make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: check it out now @dowomenfart

Comment: Much easier to help you if you drop the full code in somewhere we can play with it - like fiddle (or whatever you code playground you prefer :) )

Comment: are you trying to close the accordion whenever you click a title in the menu and then just slide that specific title content?

Comment: no content is sliding up but the icon class toggle is not, i want to change it back to angle-right instead of angle-down @zeidanbm

Comment: not sure how you're achieving the sliding with this js if you had the css would be easier but check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvuhes6m/1/) might get you started

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to switch out the icon it is probably simpler to just toggle the rotate class on it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');

    //Toggle icon
    $('.accordian-toggle i.fa-angle-right').removeClass('fa-rotate-90');
    $(this).children('i.fa-angle-right').toggleClass('fa-rotate-90');

    });

  });
```

This is untested...tough to work on without a fiddle to fiddle with!

Comment: That's not my question, adding a class is the same, i'm asking how do i toggle back the icon when clicking on another div

Comment: Ahh--sorry about that.  I've updated the response.  You can simply remove the `fa-rotate-90` class from all icons prior to adding it to the one you're clicking on, thus it takes off any prior ones on all accordion items, then just adds it to the active click.